# Cypher query for assigning property values in an arbitrary number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a Neo4J beginner, so, apologies in advance if my question is too trivial.

I am trying to create a Neo4J graph representing a set of consecutive steps in a game, as shown [in this diagram](http://prntscr.com/m6cfvm).

You will see in the diagram that I start with zero points, and, at certain steps (but not in *every* step), additional points are accumulated.

I want to assign points to nodes that don't have points yet, according to the following principle: whenever a node does not have points, I want to assign to it a number of points equal to the points possessed by the closest previous node that has points assigned to it. In the sample diagram, step 2 would have 0 points `(:Step {id: 2, points_so_far: 0})`, and step 4 would have 1 point `(:Step {id: 4, points_so_far: 1})`. Note that there may be an arbitrary number of scoreless nodes between nodes that do have a score.

Any help in creating a respective Cypher query would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
match (s:Step) WHERE not exists(s.points_so_far) 
match (prev:Step)<-[:HAS_PREVIOUS_STEP*]-(s) where exists(prev.points_so_far) 
with s, head(collect(prev)) as prev
SET s.points_so_far = prev.points_so_far
```

**How does it work ?**

First, find all nodes that have no `points_so_far`

```
match (s:Step) WHERE not exists(s.points_so_far)
```

with that nodes, find all previous steps that have `points_so_far`

```
match (prev:Step)<-[:HAS_PREVIOUS_STEP*]-(s) where exists(prev.points_so_far)
```

get all the previous nodes with points, collect them in a list, and keep only the first one encountered

```
with s, head(collect(prev)) as prev
```

set the value of the node, with the value of the previous node

```
SET s.points_so_far = prev.points_so_far
```

**Note:** 
This request uses variable path length (the `*` in `<-[:HAS_PREVIOUS_STEP*]-`) wich has some performance cost.